# Autofit text-box to text in div

Tags: html, css, image

Ok, I don't really know how to explain what I'm looking for exactly, but I know what I want(I just can't get there). I have an image link with text on top of it in a kind of paragraph box.

My concern is that I want the box to adjust in size to the quantity of text that I put in.

Here is **[a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XNrbK/)** of what I have so far.

```
.imagetext {
  left:auto;
  right:auto;
}
```

Is something else I have tried, but doesn't do what I want.

What I want is that the black box is sized to 'fit' the text. Is this possible?

Or do I have to manually size it?

P.S. The img links go to a website that is currently not in service. All the code for what I need is right in demo.

**EDIT:** I guess what I want is the black box to wrap the text instead of the image. Is this possible?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want since the black box already expands according to it's content. http://jsfiddle.net/XNrbK/2/

Comment: You question is pretty vague, cause implies lots of sub-question from our side. Dealing with `table` elements is the right way to go, but you did not specified the images behavior, the table max width and lots of other things. so the best we can do is tap in the mist.

Comment: I only want the black box to be the size of the text. not the size of the image. So there  is all that black space that I don't want in the first two. The 3rd one only works cause the text just happens to be long enough to fit right.

Comment: What other information do you need to be able to help?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNrbK/13/)

I Deleted the absolute positioning and added:

```
.imagetext {
   display: table;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Because of the absolute positioning and left: 5px; right: 5px; the text was given a width until 5 pixels from the edge of the image. The margin-top is to get the text inside the image on the desired height.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That looks closer to what I am wanting. Thanks for the help. I'll definitely play around with it.

Comment: @DaSquid No problem, if it helps mark it as helpfull!

Comment: I would, but I don't have the reputation to vote up yet.